# Having issues with parts of code in a text adventure I'm working on. What should I do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a working text game in Python that I can maybe port to a different program to make into an actual game. I got a base code, tried it out, and added on to it, but when I did, the entire program fell apart.

The code I added was not anything different from any of the already existing code. I have searched for hours to try and find some solution, to no avail.

This is the part I'm having the largest issue with.

```py
def load_tiles():
    """Parses a file that describes the world space into the _world object"""
    with open('resources/map.txt', 'r') as f:
        rows = f.readlines()
    x_max = len(rows[0].split('\t'))
    for y in range(len(rows)):
        cols = rows[y].split('\t')
        for x in range(x_max):
            tile_name = cols[x].replace('\n', '')
            if tile_name == 'StartingRoom':
                global starting_position
                starting_position = (x, y)
            _world[(x, y)] = None if tile_name == '' else getattr(__import__('tiles'), tile_name)(x, y)
```

(`tile_name = cols[x].replace('\n', '')` is the line with the issue)

I expect the code to understand that the new enemies, items, and map tiles are supposed to be integrated into the game, but it seems to reject them. This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/adventuretutorial/text-adventure-tut-master/adventuretutorial/game.py", line 31, in <module>
    play()
  File "/home/pi/adventuretutorial/text-adventure-tut-master/adventuretutorial/game.py", line 10, in play
    world.load_tiles()
  File "/home/pi/adventuretutorial/text-adventure-tut-master/adventuretutorial/world.py", line 24, in load_tiles
    tile_name = cols[x].replace('\n', '')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Without seeing the data I assume you have a row which doesn't have `x_max` columns in it.

Comment: If you're dealing with tab delimited data, use the [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: How would I add a column piece to the code without ruining another part of the code? And how would the csv module be used correctly in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using first row's size (number of columns) to iterate through other rows columns and some of them are smaller than the first row. Change the code to:

```
def load_tiles():
    """Parses a file that describes the world space into the _world object"""
    with open("resources/map.txt", "r") as f:
        rows = f.readlines()
    for y in range(len(rows)):
        cols = rows[y].split("\t")
        x_max = len(cols)
        for x in range(x_max):
            tile_name = cols[x].replace("\n", "")
            if tile_name == "StartingRoom":
                global starting_position
                starting_position = (x, y)
            _world[(x, y)] = (
                None
                if tile_name == ""
                else getattr(__import__("tiles"), tile_name)(x, y)
            )
```

Comment: Whenever I try that code, it says that "rows" is not defined. What's the issue with that?

Comment: That was just a snippet... I edited my answer and put all the code this time.

Comment: Thanks. That code fixed my problem, but a new code error rose. I will make a new question to help it get fixed. Look out for it.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming the first row has at most the same amount of columns as following rows.

For your error, you must have a row with fewer columns than the first row.

A better way to iterate over sequences, when you want to also know the index, is to use enumerate:

```
for y, row in enumerate(rows):
    for x, col in enumerate(row.split('\t')):
        tile_name = col.replace('\n', '')
        # etc
```

Also, to avoid all the splitting and stripping, you can use the [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module with `\t` as a delimiter instead of a comma:

```
import csv

with open('resources/map.txt') as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for y, row in enumerate(rows):
        for x, col in enumerate(row):
            tile_name = col
            # etc
```

Comment: When I put this code in, it says that csv is not defined; do I have to download something to make it work?

Comment: I take it you imported the csv module?

Comment: I have not specifically tried that, I just put import csv in, but I will try and find a csv module that will work.

Comment: There's probably an error in your code. It's difficult to troubleshoot. If you can't get the code I've posted to work, and don't understand the error message you're getting, read about how to create a [mcve] and, possibly, ask a new question.